# Firestore Rules: Multiple paths in a single match statement

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

For Firestore, let's say I want to use the same rules for two different collections: data and groups. How can I do this? The Rule below doesn't seem correct.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match 
      /data/{document=**}
      /groups/{document=**}
    {
      allow read: if false;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried:

```
// Option 1
match 
  /data/{document=**}
  /groups/{document=**}
{ ...

// Option 2
match ( /data/{document=**} || /groups/{document=**} ) { ...

// Option 3
match /data/{document=**} || match /groups/{document=**} { ...
```

But all these options return an error saying this syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Do you need to set the same rules for two collections or for all collections in the database?

Comment: For just these two.

Comment: So there are other collections besides these two, right?

Comment: Yes, correct, I've just taken out a specific part of the complete rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to use multiple `match` clauses for one set of rules.

The only trick I know of is to make a `match` clause for all collections, and then check the collection name in the condition too:

```
match /{collection}/{document=**} {
  allow read: if collection != 'data' && collection != 'groups';
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, you will have to duplicate (some part of) the rules across multiple `match` clauses.

If the rules get more complex, the easiest I can think of is to put the rule in a named function and then call that in both `match` clauses.

As another alternative, you can change the data model to nest the two collections under a common parent collection/document, and then define the rule there.